# Plotting a solution of an integral in 3d surface (ERROR)

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

First of all, I am sorry for any inconvenience and my rusty english.

I am trying to plot a graph of an Integral solution, and I am facing the same error "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". when I use a simpler function instead of f(x,chi), the code generates the graph correctly.

Does anyone have a clue of what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m 
import scipy as sp
import cmath as c 
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import gamma

k = 0.1


def solnum(x, chi, y):                  

    Bk = ((2*(k))**(3/2))*((1+(1.5*abs(k))))*(gamma((1/(2*abs(k)))+(3/4))/gamma((1/(2*(k)))-(3/4)))

    C = (chi/(2*(np.pi)**(0.5)))

    R1 = (1/(1+(y**2)))

    R21 = ((k**2)*(-((chi**2)*((x-y)**2))/4))

    R22 = ((1+((k**2)*(-((chi**2)*((x-y)**2))/4)**2))**(0.5))

    R23 = (R21-R22)/(k**2 - 1)

    R3 = (((((1+((k**2)*(-((chi**2)*((x-y)**2))/4)**2))**(0.5))) + ((k*(-((chi**2)*((x-y)**2))/4))))**(1/k))  

    sn = (C*Bk*R1*R23*R3)

    return sn


def f(x,chi):                          

    j = lambda y: solnum(x, chi, y)  
    resint = integrate.quad(j, -200, 200)
    return (resint[0]) 


x = np.linspace(-40.,40.,num=200)
chi = np.linspace(0.05, 0.50, num=200)
x, chi = np.meshgrid(x,chi)
z = f(x,chi)


fig = plt.figure()
grafico = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = grafico.plot_surface(x, chi, z)

plt.show()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/pwadmin/Desktop/testeimpressao.py", line 51, in <module>
    z = f(x,chi)
  File "c:/Users/pwadmin/Desktop/testeimpressao.py", line 44, in f
    resint = integrate.quad(j, -200, 200)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using numpy.vectorize

```
ax.plot_surface(x, chi, np.vectorize(solan)(x,chi), cmap=cm.YlOrRd, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```